# Pour me a drink, will you?

Tags: code-golf, string

#### The Challenge

I am thirsty and need a drink, but I don't know what to order. Your task is to provide me with either a drink or options for one.

#### I/O

Input will be either a *base* or a *drink name*.

If given a *base*, your program should output *one random* drink from a list of drinks with that base.
If given a *drink name*, your program should output the *base* that drink is made from.

Below is a list of drink names, ordered by their bases:

```
Absinthe:
    Death in the Afternoon
    Earthquake
    Green Russians
    Green Vesper
    Moloko Plus

Beer: 
    Black and Tan
    Black Velvet
    Boilermaker
    Michelada
    Irish Car Bomb

Brandy:
    B&B
    Brandy Alexander
    French Connection
    Horse's Neck
    Sidecar

Cachaça:
    Caipirinha
    Leite de Onça
    Quentão
    Rabo-de-Galo
    Royce

Gin:
    Bramble
    Casino
    Clover Club Cocktail
    Gin Fizz
    Martini

Rum:
    Bacardi
    Cuba Libre
    Daiquiri
    El Presidente
    Piña Colada

Tequila:
    El Toro Loco
    Margarita
    Matador
    Paloma
    Tequila Sunrise

Vodka:
    Black Russian
    Bloody Mary
    Cosmopolitan
    Kamikaze
    Screwdriver

Whiskey:
    Bourbon Lancer
    Irish Coffee
    Manhattan
    Rusty Nail
    Whiskey Sour
```

#### Rules:

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If given a *base*, the program's output should be *non-deterministic*, meaning that multiple runs should result in different outputs.
- Accordingly, when given a *drink name*, the program's output should be *deterministic*, yielding the same result for drinks with the same base.
- You may assume the input will always be one of the bases or drink names in the list compiled above.
- You may choose to print characters such as `ç`, `ñ` and `ã` as `c`, `n` and `a`, respectively.
- You may accept I/O in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

#### Test Cases:

```
Input:                    Output (Any one of the following):
Absinthe                  Death in the Afternoon
                          Earthquake
                          Green Russians
                          Green Vesper
                          Moloko Plus

Beer                      Black and Tan
                          Black Velvet
                          Boilermaker
                          Michelada
                          Irish Car Bomb

Brandy                    B&B
                          Brandy Alexander
                          French Connection
                          Horse's Neck
                          Sidecar

Cachaça                   Caipirinha
                          Leite de Onça
                          Quentão
                          Rabo-de-Galo
                          Royce

Gin                       Bramble
                          Casino
                          Clover Club Cocktail
                          Gin Fizz
                          Martini

Rum                       Bacardi
                          Cuba Libre
                          Daiquiri
                          El Presidente
                          Piña Colada

Tequila                   El Toro Loco
                          Margarita
                          Matador
                          Paloma
                          Tequila Sunrise

Vodka                     Black Russian
                          Bloody Mary
                          Cosmopolitan
                          Kamikaze
                          Screwdriver

Whiskey                   Bourbon Lancer
                          Irish Coffee
                          Manhattan
                          Rusty Nail
                          Whiskey Sour
```

Likewise, the input can be any of the drink names in the output column. If so, the output should be the corresponding base.

Comment: From the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14317/74163)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino sure, no problem. Those are common in my language, so I think I just put them there automatically hahahah. I'll update the rules to account for that.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, kinda weird that a language that consists almost exclusively of Unicode characters can't handle Unicode characters...

Comment: Damn now I want a drink at it's only 10am

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>693</s> <s>690</s> <s>686</s> 687 bytes

Yeah, naive approach. I tried some compression methods, and this one seems to be the shortest.

*-2 bytes thanks to [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino).*

EDIT: Bug fixed.

```python
import random
v="Absinthe$Death in the Afternoon$Earthquake$Green Russians$Green Vesper$Moloko Plus$Beer$Black and Tan$Black Velvet$Boilermaker$Michelada$Irish Car Bomb$Brandy$B&B$Brandy Alexander$French Connection$Horse's Neck$Sidecar$Cachaca$Caipirinha$Leite de Onca$Quentao$Rabo-de-Galo$Royce$Gin$Bramble$Casino$Clover Club Cocktail$Gin Fizz$Martini$Rum$Bacardi$Cuba Libre$Daiquiri$El Presidente$Pina Colada$Tequila$El Toro Loco$Margarita$Matador$Paloma$Tequila Sunrise$Vodka$Black Russian$Bloody Mary$Cosmopolitan$Kamikaze$Screwdriver$Whiskey$Bourbon Lancer$Irish Coffee$Manhattan$Rusty Nail$Whiskey Sour".split('$');a=v.index(input());print(v[a-a%6if a%6else random.randint(1,5)+a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVLBbtNAEL3zFaNqIIkgkRCCS9VDHNqCSEtoonBAHMbrCR55vePurkPTnw9jZLh4d9Zv3nv7ZrtTrjW8O5@l7TRmiBQqbV8cry6WZZKQa8aPTLkGCWAFLA@ZY1ANeE0x1489NYy3kTnAQ5@SUEhjuefUccQ79doobHyfsGA7KDy5BkwGdhTGas/@yBkLFc@xNUrrE1ezp4rwc5RUw4oiFNqWWAwWT1i8KsYtLD0/2caabiIHZ1gNgV0Wc/lJY@JJgnt2DW6lYkcRV@RqcmSrdBIl1IRrlsxQMXwN9uNbzyGT4gOVOq94fkveCj05u6uEQbctPVu/RaS48nrkCCvflybtmkziBxzcyPMz3llOEgQf@hYLU42V4KovCdZSRkuX5LE3E3jtYRM5mcWQGTcSyMj@BrBjQ3gaEDuNCmt1OtD@oiiZbJep0ogbM9n@R8O2DxYc416rhsacxxFZpWrBGccJV5pa7dQbVcAv1EpDz4xbF/l3FcUuht9rSQ1b5NrHUgOsKTg7HueihwOzmbAU80BhGvkE90MGYyNsrfFikTrTmE5wMrukq@NCbGJPUwldn6ez2WVnc8jT4w@a08sPcgD7sk88PsjFsAyAt2/ez17Tz9n5/O99/gE)

Comment: Thanks to the new rules you can save some bytes by getting rid of the accents.

Comment: [637 bytes](http://bit.ly/2AZbVc2) using Python 2 and string compression

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 356 bytes

```
“%³“¥;ġŀṭṢDṡỌµ“Ñçḥ“)ụ_ƥÐ¬“(OE⁼Ọ“"³Ḟ'×ɱA8“tẊ“ßDæj|t³G“z⁸ƈƲe“¦¿¶“ßṆÑẆṇ8“©ŒẓġṾɠ×“¢(°“⁶oI“¬ĿḤẈX“ṫ°^iɱ“ıịṣXṆẠL“3!ṁ“©VṢ“¦ƈœƘNd]¶mḄœ“Ðv4WṁḌạYÐġȯḣɼ“¢ḅuɼḶŒß“AṠḍ*ɦ)!Ḷ¿µʋ“¡pK“¡ȯL“¦uż“¬5;“¥I¢q9ḅḋĖ“µ>Ƥøŀ“ ØÐ“¤^(“¡Il“£Ḅ#ṫ$⁽ø“€Uy“"ƭ/4¢ṫ“ƬƒN⁼A6+EẈṆ“8ɠ¹“½oŒLụ}ɗ“µṡ⁴“½Çj“€g©“ÆḄ²zị'“¥¹j“þk¥ÆṢ“C⁼ṭ¬'“¿®ı“÷Ụ;“1ṂY“?]ʂ“¢ȥ4Ɗh⁺“Œ\ẒƘḳ“µċ$“¦ʋȷ[Ɱ“¡?ƓṚĠk»
¢i³
¢_¢’¤%6¤¤¢+5X¤¤¢%6¤’¤?ị1£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVL/S1NRFP@9vyJLceYPIU0xhMZIiZHZT9WkVIKkNldWzEAp2Bs1hzOYb5ArIvc9xE2da/Pet@ng3Pcee/svzvtH1rlXHtx7Pp9z7vnyOS@8GolsDgZu7PcINOiE8oyZt2LIa8gLs8jz2N6FJjnEnviLrEzWGLbLK3ZZpKFKyPN4ztU6FEX2DWgg@zMq9p26f5pwFI0d@fRgVlTCn6PQeEBoy9WYnbTPVmW1CnShpUKQJ8QeGgnk2/IpHFo6Ghkzj/zSyYl9SRU8cEq3q7XWAxJXzS6yEhrJICHkR3C6HHLqZJt1bKeQF4OUFI3cPFF3hpBrKu9TGkyVtpNWxs4uvFqC1ltkX62M7CP9yfuMIpHtopFfFGkz3ztBVnQ6qgFk3zacDrKWpYsDYvzIc8i@33IqY0PE0jDNfkpG5t8/VFfvZF7V2rBUgurkjNI4AIUPdykZspT5QzLNe3ZJMCtG9nWRFWnJlZY9KkcgIq8itXiThhx2tQvBpAzx6pNNKbpdu@2l1vgRAbtq6wu0D//U@BwJQ/MTOe3kgMscF@uWPk/b@@IoPZu0Xlf7pzxiO3yV8zUcSh0SVA7OtkjHUdUxcOkXl2tQJp9S8L7cO69BVUV04diU2otzbJfklBPI44t0@5b6cSVer@y1d964mkHI0l@godtZZOqna5qpYaVTP9U7f@7Wj9XgPjuD/JeZW4P2NSiEoEHnClDpn1AamYISfYXxyeCVIQnl8VHPE1AcDAaPXn6Mht6F/gM)

Formula stolen from Colera Su but I think I can get it shorter in Jelly using a Jelly-mindset approach.

**¢_¢**

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>681 680 676 661</s> 646+1 bytes

**gz version:**

```php
<?=($x=explode)(_,$x(X,strstr($d=gzinflate(base64_decode("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")),$argn.X))[1])[rand()%5]?:array_slice($x(X,strstr($d,$argn,1)),-2)[0];
```

**strtr version, <s>676</s> 661+1 bytes**

```php
<?=($x=explode)(_,$x(X,strstr($d=strtr("Abs4theXDeath 4 the Aft2noon_E5thquake_Green Russi0s_Green Vesp2_Moloko PlusXBe2XMiche7da1 0d T01 Velvet_Boil2mak2_I8sh C5 BombXBr0dyXB&B_Br0dy Alex0d2_French Connection_Horse's Neck_Sidec5XCachacaXCaipi8nha_Leite de Onca_Quentao_Rabo-de-Galo_RoyceXG4XG4 Fizz9rt4i_Bramble_Cas4o_Clov2 Club CocktailXRumXBac5di_Cuba Libre_Daiqui8_P4a Co7da_El Presidente66 Sun8se_El Toro Loco9rg5ita9tador_PalomaXVodkaXBloody M5y1 Russi0_Cosmopolit0_Screwd8v2_Kamikaze33 Sour_Bourbon L0c2_I8sh Coffee9nhatt0_Rusty Nail",[an,_Black,er,XWhiskey,in,ar,XTequila,la,ri,_Ma]),$argn.X))[1])[rand()%5]?:array_slice($x(X,strstr($d,$argn,1)),-2)[0];
```

Run as pipe with `-nF` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85a3b97b842844311829fd2f890aeb23c32b6476). Requires PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 640 bytes

```python
import random as r
def f(s):d="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".decode('base64').decode('zip').split('.');i=d.index(s);print d[[i+r.randint(1,5),i/6*6][i%6>0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZJLb6JQAIX3/RXGpFFrIy95OE0nQQEFBRFBlKYL5F7l8i5cFPjzjjOLWX7n5JzVV7Q4zDP68UBpkZe4V/oZyNOeX/XKFwAvvcuwGv0Cn32o3WdOgFu6E3Vi7gZ0Yt4l9txy2NKOxi3KkLyOogUSRRiTuLgcWxRxTnLyM9gclxynJvmqyep0m4v5XJWM@rwuU6hK0CLHXph7Gdt4J3t8VH@sJNwHtcJ4QuW20X3Pm3Or3l5bz17mSzJszQLFXGDyCTqxG6/gRT3z93OdcGWT6tbigmQNyaPoVZiXs1DwZyfLKDKiCRfIooFxtw8HO3EQezbYKRSUY5QaUFtAuUvpRPTWijJmkVptQ6V2Wyx2t2UmjCW3O0SbwKEBYwJh5uzYK9VYjHJgaDthUlIGSpjStM14uTDrFC6y3Ljs7lNFqQ2m1bJ4p8yIrWy7HXUsF2A7XWMw53Gcdbq8Uy963QZ70nba8moXtsSva0m9B4jUVT6dJ3iDMRrHZJ2ki5JiS7SJDYMwwiaNoHqyZ76JTV8wE/latdfaXPMnt8iqU5RWyorYawsTLEVCGzvETQ4vEjPdOrFvtClPduGeKlBtUkfYCF4@3ZGuBjZLbXULNiVZyT@hrKvEffXDgYPenwAY5AAOB2e/gtx0MPofdKh4UlUkCA8Hk8HoA32CCcoAbJ7ufBQlynAPfH2hcTn5a9cTh9Q7O3pHBPfGfX@hV@43@f39uAwHVl3htmf4KBmMXv4NX2ADg/6zmkNYPq/7bxT5@AM)

Comment: Use `from random import*` instead of `import random as r`, and omit the `r.` from `r.randint`, so it will save you 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 628 bytes

Stealing the best ideas from others... thanks for the inflate trick

```
<?$d=explode("|",gzinflate(base64_decode("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")));$i=array_search($argv[1],$d);echo($i%6)?$d[$i-$i%6]:$d[$i+rand(1,5)];
```

Comment: You are wasting 22-1 bytes. But nice idea. Try `<?=($d=explode(_,gzinflate(...)))[($i=array_flip($d)[$argn])‌​-($i%6?:-rand(1,5)];` with `-nF` and `_` as separator instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>381</strike> 375 bytes

```
≔⪪”}⊞J'%↓B+K…↙ZＱαyε↘¶⎚\`⟲≧↑lⅉ＆⬤↖ΦüY⁹←‖⧴p×OＣ∧⊗F]±⊗✳Ｎ″ⅈ✳c∕lü,Π438↖⍘✳⍘⁷N⪪ςz↨Ｄ″≦«p¶↧⟦¬²◨▶↗⪫/_"b8n↨À⊙ρ≡1#▶UD⸿no,7φ²↘↑r‴m⪪pＷ⭆mC↥#pP″νr↧″h[κznβd6qυ:*…KC⪫⌈⸿＆DΣεＸMω⊙⟧↔Ｌ↓;?ü↶σ⁵%Ｆ⊙⪫:ＱD*)⊞↥$Ｘ4.⎆V\`″Ｎb5βς｜…5¤⁴↘⊗｜%À⭆)⬤,⁻f»Ｄh…{“ [ＷＦ⸿⊗$ς«8RbγＺ5gv⮌⟲Π\`XcρO≦3；2{§³Ｑψt‹ＳY⪫ς⦃Ｄ⪫⎚TO⁼Ｎ⊗Ｅ⁺ζt≕·´H|›gＰＯＷkＫ⁶³⧴\`⁶Ａ⊟ⅈ✂&)ξ↧εβ%ιSΦＹ\`»ＸＷV⁸｜∧Ａ▷RE⍘Zα#÷Þ~↙{﹪ÞqＳＫ[μO\`It›▷≕ρ≔⊘Jc◨;Ｚm�～8″⟲Ｐ↶S⎆2×”#δ≔⌕δθπ§δ⁻π∨﹪π⁶±⊕‽⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVLBktowDL33Kzxopg2z4dheeiLpst0psBQY9qzYgmjiWMFx6LI/T8VOZnOJJOs9ye/Z1hitoL/d5n3Pp5DtOs8pm8yrnkOqCX4RptpwMJqY@TFRDCIBHjGm@jxgQ/AUiYLZDorH0I/pgfqOIqzESyNm44ceCtJC4dE2BoMzewxjdiB/oQSFsKfYKqXi2Nbk0SE8R@5rU2I0hbQVFFGxVyi@FmNo5p7eNFDQIlKw2ishkE2sW/6W2NO33qzJNrBjRxYjlGhrtKh/7jhyqBGWxImMI/MS9ODvQCGhwBYrmTmaPaHXRK5W78rhPretPCleJRIovVwomtIPlY62TUL29z6z4Pd3WKlOHBi2QwuFTo2OoRwqNEuuoqqLfB50CXj0ZhOp1xVDIthwQCX7EGBP2uHx3rGXKGYpVu60J4ycUKOETiJsdMn2s9vshqDCERzENTjqPFqkmYgKpxxXKKVvpRP1XA/@YMsNvhPsbKR/LrJeDF5r7htSyWWIlQSzxGC1PPoixyORLqEqpjuFzkhXs75rMALNToGT3ExgMs2Nm/78Mr60BQeXufw8zTstbtSJlM3Ts1r5puVZ1uUvMVuJG7xo/GOar@mEibKHh2yrhkubfZ9@fLfb53O5zS7@Pw)

A port to Charcoal of Colera Su's answer. Link is to the verbose version of the code. I could not test some of the cases because Charcoal considers `French Connection` as two different inputs...

- 6 bytes saved thanks to Neil!

Comment: `Print(AtIndex(d,-(p,Or(Modulo(p,6),Negate(++(Random(5))))));` saves you a few bytes. Also, to stop Charcoal splitting on spaces, either a) append a trailing newline b) wrap the input in a list i.e. `["French Connection"]`.

Comment: @Neil if you omit the last `;` of your `Print` statement, the deverbosifier omits a `¦` at the end of the code and you can save one more byte.

Comment: I guess that works... I always hate having to remove commas and semicolons though. (I need to remember to ask @ASCII-only to allow a `;` before `else`...)